# Doctrine Extension with API Platform - SQL

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4, api-platform.com

I'm working on some API Platform project.
I 'm using my API point `/references` to get some data containing subentities.

But the issue is that I use a Doctrine extension to filter my list. Using this extension I can filter which references I get.

But in the subentity Stock I stil have some data that I dont want.

My goal is to get **all stocks that have the warehouse.owner = $owner.**

Here is the code :

```
private function addWhere(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, string $resourceClass): void
{
    if ($this->security->isGranted('SCOPE admin') || !$this->security->isGranted('SCOPE logistician')) {
        return;
    }
    /** @var Client $client */
    $client = $this->security->getUser();
    $rootAlias = $queryBuilder->getRootAliases()[0];
    switch ($resourceClass) {
        case Entry::class:
        case Inventory::class:
            $queryBuilder->join(sprintf('%s.stock', $rootAlias), 's');
            break;
        case Reference::class:
            // I'm here
            $queryBuilder->join(sprintf('%s.stocks', $rootAlias), 's');
            break;
        default:
            return;
            break;
    }
    $queryBuilder->join('s.warehouse', 'w', Expr\Join::WITH, 'w.owner = :owner');
    $queryBuilder->setParameter('owner', $client->getSubject());
}
```

Here is the response :

```
{
  "@id": "/stock/references/7a00e32f-1195-43e6-a5d1-f75d64471112",
  "@type": "Reference",
  "id": "7a00e32f-1195-43e6-a5d1-f75d64471112",
  "quantityAvailable": 75,
  "quantitiesOnHand": 100,
  "quantityOfExpectedEntries": -25,
  "archived": false,
  "stocks": [
    {
      "@id": "/stock/stocks/214d9b27-d2c8-45e5-9d67-10985291022a",
      "@type": "Stock",
      "quantityOnHand": 50,
      "lastCountedEntryWasCreatedAt": "2020-07-23T10:04:32+02:00",
      "warehouse": {
        "@id": "/stock/warehouses/3a61275f-4b20-4061-a64e-52783cf4d892",
        "@type": "Warehouse",
        "id": "3a61275f-4b20-4061-a64e-52783cf4d892",
        "owner": "9001",
        "name": "Adams-Reichel",
        "createdAt": "2020-07-23T10:04:32+02:00"
      },
      "createdAt": "2020-07-23T10:04:32+02:00"
    },
    {
      "@id": "/stock/stocks/6f2a0542-d65d-489a-b96c-c8658ff195ea",
      "@type": "Stock",
      "quantityOnHand": 50,
      "lastCountedEntryWasCreatedAt": "2020-07-23T10:04:32+02:00",
      "warehouse": {
        "@id": "/stock/warehouses/cc8f3267-29b6-4ad5-9f8b-74b98aab85d6",
        "@type": "Warehouse",
        "id": "cc8f3267-29b6-4ad5-9f8b-74b98aab85d6",
        "owner": "9002",
        "name": "Steuber, Ruecker and Vandervort",
        "createdAt": "2020-07-23T10:04:32+02:00"
      },
      "createdAt": "2020-07-23T10:04:32+02:00"
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": "2020-07-23T10:04:32+02:00"
},
```

How can I filter the subentity result by just using my extension and DQL ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Extension is used for retrieve main items, not associated collection.

Instead you can use data transformer.

```php
class ReferenceOutput {
    public $stocks;
}

//Next class
use ApiPlatform\Core\DataTransformer\DataTransformerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class ReferenceOutputTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    private string $security;

    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    /**
     * Transforms the given object to something else, usually another object.
     * This must return the original object if no transformations have been done.
     *
     * @param object $object Snapshot
     *
     * @param string $to
     * @param array $context
     *
     * @return object
     */
    public function transform($object, string $to, array $context = [])
    {
        /** @var Reference $reference */
        $reference = $object;

        /** @var Client $client */
        $client = $this->security->getUser();

        $referenceOutput = new ReferenceOutput();
        $stocks = $reference->getStoks()->filter(
            static function($key, $stock) use ($client) {
            return $stock->getWarehouse()->getOwner() === $client->getSubject();
        });

        $referenceOutput->stocks = $stocks;

        return $referenceOutput;
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether the transformation is supported for a given data and context.
     *
     * @param object|array $data object on normalize / array on denormalize
     *
     * @param string $to
     * @param array $context
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function supportsTransformation($data, string $to, array $context = []): bool
    {
        return ReferenceOutput::class === $to && $data instanceof Reference;
    }
}
```